# How to put a multivariate prior in JAGS

Tags: jags

I have a model, say

```
y[i]<-dnorm (mu[i],sigma^2)
mu[i]<- x[i,1]* theta1+ x[i,2]*theta2 + b0
```

I would like to put a multivariate prior on theta1 and theta2, say
`c(theta1,theta2) ~ dmnorm (Mean, Sigma)` where Mean could be a vector (0,0) and Sigma is covariance matrix.  But the JAGS did not allow me to do it... Does anyone know how can I give a multivariate prior to theta1 and theta2?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have a multivariate node.  For example,

```
theta[1:2] ~ dmnorm(Mean[1:2], Sigma[1:2,1:2])
mu[i]<- x[i,1]* theta[1]+ x[i,2]*theta[2] + b0
```